# Javascript, storing files in JSON or in TSV for efficiency in reading and parsing?

Tags: javascript, json, file

In my code I needed to read TSV (tab-formatted) data from different files and transform it to a single file to improve the user usability. At the moment of saving the file I am facing a decision:

- Store it in JSON format where I already have the object structure I need for the next logic
- Store it again in TSV format and parse it again afterwards (or use a library such as http://papaparse.com/ or similar, don't really know what is available out there)

I have tried the first option, thinking I would save the parsing time by directly reading in JSON. 
However, file sizes of JSON data are much higher than if stored in TSV format, and perhaps what I win in not parsing the data I lose in reading much more data.

There are libraries such as http://msgpack.org/ that could help in reducing JSON file size. And perhaps there are libraries for TSV that avoid me having to parse the data again (see above). And I really don't know how efficient is the JSON.parse function, maybe I am spending a long time there.

So the question would be, **what is the best strategy when you have a javascript complex object and you want to save it in a file to read it later?**

- to store in JSON?
- or to store in TSV?

Comment: I don't understand how doing the same process you were already doing *plus* saving a second file and then reading it again could save time. Does the original source file have to be read every time the program runs? *"possibly my object structures were already this size "within the code""* - If you're talking about the size in memory, if you only retain references to the particular objects you actually need then the rest will (eventually) be garbage collected, freeing up memory.

Comment: It is also due to usability. Before the user had to e.g. submit 4 files for one analysis. If they want to compare 2 analysis, then 8 files. Now I am transforming the 4 files into 1 file (saved in JSON format), and I also thought that if in this process I stored the already parsed information, the whole process would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to optimize size, then (in addition to compression), you may want to consider using a serialization mechanism like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/index.html), [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/). There is no one right answer, but one area where TSV wins is in not duplicating the object property names when repeating many entries. Many of these serialization formats apply a similar principle (by making the schema external to the actual data that complies with that schema). Of course, this redundancy may not matter much once you run the data through a compressor like gzip, so you should really measure your files after they have been compressed to determine what is worthwhile to do. Both JSON and TSV have plenty of libraries for handling them, so which is "better" from a velocity / coding perspective seems like purely a matter of personal preference, as it should be possible to easily work with either format. As for size, just measure after you've applied compression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, I think what I was asking was about what is more efficient, to store and later parse JSON or to store and later parse TSV files. I am updating the question to reflect that and from your reply, you are saying that differences are marginal?

Comment: @Gerard, I'm saying that differences with respect to how easy it is to parse is marginal (though this will depend on the language). In terms of the size, the uncompressed size may be vastly different, but you need to measure the size when compressed (with a specific compression algorithm that you can deploy in your code) to perform a fair comparison. But if you care that much about compactness, then directly going to a serialization format that is specifically optimized for size may be a more worthwhile investment than that measurement.

Comment: I will think about compressing the files, but I am not sure of willing to do that since they can be edited if they are in plain text form. I don't really care about file size, except if file size means that Chrome will crash due to that (I'm not sure if it is reading huge files or parsing huge files the reason the browser collapses). At the end, if I assume that parsing JSON and TSV are equivalent in terms of resources, and that compression can make file sizes equivalent, then it is as you say a matter of personal preferences